# Subclassing UIWindow in iPad app

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uiwindow

I have this weird problem.. I'm building an in-house app that should register all touch events inside the app and, when a touch occurs, reset a timer. The timer checks if the user is inactive for more than 60 seconds and then logs him/her out of the system.

Now... I want to subclass UIWindow and steal all touch-events through there BUT it's impossible! [This is the great tutorial I'm following](http://blog.wyldco.com/2010/11/how-to-capture-touches-over-a-uiwebview/), (the downloadable sample works) but implemented in my project, the code doesn't work...

Here is my AppDelegate.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "TouchWindow.h"

@interface StureplansHLMAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate> {
TouchWindow *window;
Settings *appSettings;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) TouchWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Settings *appSettings;

@end
```

And here is the .m file

```
#import "StureplansHLMAppDelegate.h"
#import "TouchWindow.h"
#import "WelcomeScreen.h"

@implementation StureplansHLMAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize appSettings;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[TouchWindow alloc] init];
self.window = [[TouchWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
WelcomeScreen *startScreen = [[WelcomeScreen alloc] init];
[self.window addSubview:startScreen.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}
```

When i instantiate with my custom UIWindow class the app is just black and never loads the view...

I'm using XCode 4.2 iOS 5 and storyboard. Can someone help me? How do I get it to work?

Comment: Why are you creating one TouchWindow, then creating a second and throwing the first one away?

Comment: Also, you don't keep a pointer to startScreen, and so it will become a lost/leaked object if/when the window goes away.

Comment: I think maybe you need to set the geometry of startScreen.

Comment: Just some errors in the code i posted :) Looks alright in XCode, and the pointer is there, no difference though :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to retain startScreen somewhere. Instead of adding startScreen's view to the window with `addSubview`, simply set it as the rootViewController of the window

```
self.window.rootViewController = startScreen
```